# Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is ( Python code )

Tags: python

Error is

```
Provide your url: https://www.amazon.com/s?me=ASEVS99O6FS73&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER
Provide output file name: asd



DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65126/devtools/browser/7338744e-3e07-4b53-9449-22c7e266b226
[12048:11032:1121/082539.022:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [08:25:39.023] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[12048:11032:1121/082539.029:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [08:25:39.029] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Amazon Work.py", line 49, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
[3596] Failed to execute script 'Amazon Work' due to unhandled exception!
[12048:1184:1121/082618.612:ERROR:util.cc(129)] Can't create base directory: C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleUpdater
[6556:2384:1121/082718.378:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(537)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

The complete code is

```
search_url=input("Provide your url: ")
output=input("Provide output file name: ")

print('\n')

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver      # imports
from time import sleep
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
cdriver="chromedriver"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(cdriver)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)


# ## Changing Location ## 



driver.find_element_by_id('glow-ingress-line1').click()
time.sleep(1)
# driver.find_element_by_id('GLUXZipUpdateInput').clear()
driver.find_element_by_id('GLUXZipUpdateInput').send_keys("34236")

element=driver.find_element_by_id('GLUXZipUpdate')
ActionChains(driver).click(element).perform()
time.sleep(1)
driver.refresh()


# ## Gathering Products from Search URL 


Links=[]
driver.get(search_url)
time.sleep(5)
while 1:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
    Listings=soup.find_all('div',{"data-component-type":"s-search-result"})
    for link in Listings:
        if link not in Links: ### no duplicates
            Links.append('https://www.amazon.com/dp/'+link('a',{"class":"a-link-normal a-text-normal"})[0]['href'].split('/dp/')[1].split('/')[0])

    checker=soup.find("span",{"class":"s-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-disabled"})
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Next').click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        break

print('\n')       
print("Total Product Found: "+str(len(Links)))
print('\n')


# ## All Functions 



def Csv_Download(Records,output):
    file=pd.DataFrame(Records,columns=['Product Name','Description','Unique ID','Price','Estimated Delivery','main Image','Additional Image 1','Additional Image 2','Additional Image 3','Additional Image 4','Additional Image 5','Additional Image 6','Additional Image 7','Additional Image 8','Additional Image 9','Additional Image 10'])
    file.to_csv(str(output)+'.csv', index=False, encoding="utf-8-sig")

def All_Product_Info(soup):
    
    ## title // Price // ASIN 
    
    product_title=soup.find("span",{"id":"productTitle"}).text.strip()
    product_title=product_title.strip()
    
    try:
        price=soup.find("span",{"id":"price_inside_buybox"}).text.strip()
    except:
        try:
            price=soup.find('span',{"id":"newBuyBoxPrice"}).text
        except:
            price=""
        
    un_id=driver.current_url.split('/dp/')[-1].split('/')[0]
    

    ##################### About Section #################################
    ##################### About Section #################################
    ##################### About Section #################################
    about_section=""
    
    try:
        info1=soup.find("table",{"class":"a-normal a-spacing-micro"})
        about_section="\n"
        about_section=about_section.join(info1.text.strip().split('\n\n\n\n\n'))
        about_section=about_section.replace('\n\n\n',": ")
        about_section=about_section.strip()
        #print(about_section)
    except:
        pass
    
    try:
        info2=soup.find('ul',{"class":"a-unordered-list a-vertical a-spacing-mini"})('li')
        string=""
        for points in info2:
            string=string+"\n"+points.text.strip().replace('\n'," ")
        
        info2=string.strip()  ####### Info2 te string er shob input kora holo ekhane.......
        #print(info2)
        about_section=about_section+"\n"+info2
    except:
        pass
    
    about_section=about_section.strip()
    
    
    ##################### Delivery Section #################################
    ##################### Delivery Section #################################
    
    delivery=""
    try:
        delivery=soup.find("span",{"id":"upsell-message"}).text
        delivery=delivery.split('\n\n\n\n')[0].strip().replace('\n\n',"").replace('Details',"").replace('\n',"")
    except:
        try:
            delivery=soup.find("div",{"id":"mir-layout-DELIVERY_BLOCK-slot-DELIVERY_MESSAGE"}).text.strip().replace('\n\n',"").replace('Details',"").replace('\n',"")
        except:
            #print("Problem in Delivery Section....................")
            pass
        
    return product_title, about_section, un_id, price, delivery.strip()


################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$#################################################
################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$#################################################


def Getting_Image_Links():
    Images=[]
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id('imgTagWrapperId').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

        ## First Image .................

        all_images=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="ivThumb"]')
        img_link=soup.find('div',{"id":"ivLargeImage"})('img')[0]['src']
        if img_link not in Images:
            Images.append(img_link)

        for image in all_images:
            image.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
            img_link=soup.find('div',{"id":"ivLargeImage"})('img')[0]['src']

            if img_link not in Images:
                Images.append(img_link)

        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Close"]').click()
    except:
        pass
    return Images

################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$#################################################
################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$#################################################

def Image_Ordering(Images):
    main_image=""
    ad_1=""
    ad_2=""
    ad_3=""
    ad_4=""
    ad_5=""
    ad_6=""
    ad_7=""
    ad_8=""
    ad_9=""
    ad_10=""
    
    if len(Images)>0:
        for i in range(0,len(Images)):
            if i==0:
                main_image=Images[i]     
            if i==1:
                ad_1=Images[i]
            if i==2:
                ad_2=Images[i]
            if i==3:
                ad_3=Images[i]
            if i==4:
                ad_4=Images[i]
            if i==5:
                ad_5=Images[i]
            if i==6:
                ad_6=Images[i]
            if i==7:
                ad_7=Images[i]
            if i==8:
                ad_8=Images[i]
            if i==9:
                ad_9=Images[i]
            if i==10:
                ad_10=Images[i]
    
    return main_image,ad_1,ad_2,ad_3,ad_4,ad_5,ad_6,ad_7,ad_8,ad_9,ad_10


# # Running Portion 

# In[ ]:


Records=[]  
for i in range(len(Links)):
    link=Links[i]
    for run in range(3):
        try:
            driver.get(link)
            print(str(i)+": "+link+" | Out of "+str(len(Links)))
            time.sleep(3)
            
            soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
            product_info=All_Product_Info(soup)  ######## Main Function ########
            if product_info[-2]=="":
                driver.refresh()
                time.sleep(2)
                soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
                product_info=All_Product_Info(soup)

            ######### Image Section ###########
            ######### Image Section ###########
            Images=Getting_Image_Links()
            All_Images=Image_Ordering(Images)
            print()
            Records.append((product_info[0],product_info[1],product_info[2],product_info[3],product_info[4],All_Images[0],All_Images[1],All_Images[2],All_Images[3],All_Images[4],All_Images[5],All_Images[6],All_Images[7],All_Images[8],All_Images[9],All_Images[10]))
            if len(Records)%15==0:
                time.sleep(2)
                CSV_output=Csv_Download(Records,output)
             
                
            break
        
        except:
            print("\nTrying Again")
            time.sleep(3)
    
CSV_output=Csv_Download(Records,output)
p=input("Finished Running, Press any key to close... ")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coCdI.jpg)

Error is shown in the attached image
Initially this was working fine few months back
This code scrapes Amazon website and outputs a csv file
I used this script after 5 months.
I downloaded and used the chromedriver according to my current chrome version[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97kMM.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TKJ0.jpg)

Comment: The important part is actually "IndexError: list index out of range". The line before the error says that this occurs on line 49 of your script. What line is that?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: line 49 is file.to_csv(str(output)+'.csv', index=False, encoding="utf-8-sig")